# Swift 2 - Introspection: Check for Bool vs. Int

Tags: swift2, introspection

I'm trying to check the type of a property at runtime. My problem is, that I cannot distinguish Bool from Int.
Let's consider the class:

```
class MyObject: NSObject {

    var boolProperty: Bool = true

}
```

Now both of the following wil output 2 times `true`

```
let myObject = MyObject()
let prop: Any = myObject.valueforKey("boolProperty")! as Any

print(prop is Bool)
print(prop is Int)
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29151499/bool-being-seen-as-int-when-using-anyobject) is a similar problem, but the solution won't work somehow.

Comment: In your example the `valueForKey` line throws an error and you –  the developer – should know the type.

Comment: You cannot really check the exact type of a value type at runtime. Not in Swift. In 99% of cases you shouldn't need to do that.

Comment: `prop.dynamicType` will tell you `__NSCFBoolean.Type`. It might be helpful if you would provide an example of why you want to do this, though, because maybe there's a better way to do what you want.

Comment: No `prop.dynamicType` will tell `_NSCFNumber` and that's where the problem comes from.

Comment: @vadian: I'm not getting an eyception on exact the same code. Also it is possible not to know the type as the developer. With this argumentation you can also consider generics useless.